# Tables creates strange symbols

Tags: tabularx

In my appendix I have a bunch of tables, all of them similar formatted. Now, between two of them LaTeX adds some strange symbols after compiling the document to pdf:

> ! >X>>X!>>X!|

I am now wondering, why they appear (only between two tables and not between the others) und how to suppress this.

I cannot give you an MWE, as I do not want to bother you with my whole document, but I can give you an dummy table as example for table formatting:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bicaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{16cm}{!{\vline[1.5pt]}>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X!{\vline[0.0pt]}>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X!{\vline[0.5pt]}>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X!{\vline[1.5pt]}}
\noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
    \multicolumn{3}{!{\vline[1.5pt]}c!{\vline[1.5pt]}}{Randbedingungen} \\
\noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
Variable & Unit & Value  \\
\noalign{\hrule height 1.5pt}
\end{tabularx}
 \end{center}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
  \bicaption[indention=0pt]{Unterschrift}{Caption}\label{tab:example}
\vspace*{5.8mm}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: without a MWE I doubt any useful help can be offered. You should always be able to make a MWE, start from a copy of your document and delete everything you can checking at each stage that the problem still appears. then post a one-table document showing the problem.

Comment: `! >X>>X!>>X!|` looks like a partially typeset `{!{}XX>{\raggedright}X}` column specification. Which presumably means you have an error in the table markup. Do you get no tex error?

Comment: I clearly understands the point with the MWE, still in this case its not working. When I remove more and more of the tables the error vanishes. I also copied the head of other table to the two table before and after the error with no effect.

Comment: That is expected. If you delete something and the problem goes, put that back and delete something else. It is highly unlikely that you need more than 1 page in an example.

Comment: Oh I forgot, no I didn't get an error.

Comment: Tomorrow I will again try to narrow the error down. So far I know only no differences in setup of the tables. If I remove a lot of them it vanishes. Furthermore, if I bring a \pagebreak between the two tables, I can move the error from one page to the other.

Comment: @Jäger, try to make a test with copy of your document in which you replace yours tables with table in my answer. if your problem still persist than the cause of your problem is not in tables. if with this the problem is eliminated, than return your tables (one by one) and see in which one is source of problem.

Comment: After searching all tables, I finally found a part of a header '!{\vline[1.5pt]}>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X!{\vline[0.0pt]}>...' between two tables, but on a totally different location. @ David and Zarko: Thank you so much for leading me a clear path to a solution. As this is only a mistake from my side, I will vote to delete this (stupid) question!

Answer (score 1):

**edit:**
i apparently i misunderstand the question ... and correct table, which is not issue of question :) . since i found errors in table code i made proposition for better table's code. so the question is still open and can't be answered before we see the *mwe* which demonstrate the main problem

i guess that you like to obtain table something like this (now consider op comment):

[image]

code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

%\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bicaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\makegapedcells
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{16cm}{|>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X|
                            >{\hsize=0.6\hsize}C|
                            >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}C|
                            }
\xhline{1.5pt}
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Randbedingungen} \\
Variable & Unit & Value  \\
\xhline{1.5pt}
\end{tabularx}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex}
  \bicaption{Unterschrift}{Caption}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: not sure this answers the question of where the `X>X` comes from

Comment: i test op *mwe* and i didn't see anything that remain me  on X>X. however, all cells contain [1.5pt] on beginning. do i miss something? since i found code quite strange and unnecessary complicated i made proposition, how to set table more simple and with working code.

Comment: the output from the OP's code looks more or less same as  this (it does not print `1.5pt]` ?) , but the OPs code isn't an example of the problem in the question that is asked, which is why some unshown code prints `>>>`

Comment: @ Zarko: Thanks for proposing the improvement. Actually I need to have these two line thicknesses and also the skipping of the line between first and second column is intended.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you have right. actually i solve a problem for which op didn't ask :-). and as stated in comments below questions, we cant help op if he will not  provide *mwe* which demonstrate his problem. which is (now i see) out of tables.

Comment: @Jäger, just delete this line :). sorry that i misunderstand your question. however i find errors in your table code and i try to remove them.

Comment: @Zarko yes I wasn't really objecting, I was just surprised after telling the Op that the question couldn't be answered to notice the site front page flagging an answer posted so I came back to see the answer...:-)